# Android Facebook Messenger keyboard resize activity layout

Tags: android

I trying to fix layout resize in my `Activity` when keyboard appear on the screen. I've tried to put in `manifest` on the `activity`: `windowsSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"` but with not results, my `layout` is still resizing when I open the `keyboard` with someone on messenger which is unussual.

Comment: `windowsSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHideen"` is wrongly spelled. It's `windowsSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`

Comment: In app is written correctly, sorry, I just wrote my question from computer when I had the code on laptop and didn't copy paste. This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing what I think you are doing, `stateAlwaysHidden` is not the way to go about it.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  >
```

From the documentation

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing.

This is, I think what you want. The pan not to change

Here's a link to the documentation regarding it http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.